# Onsen: carousel swipe between tabs in tabbar

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

I am using Onsen UI to set up a mobile app.
Now I have something like this:

```
<ons-tabbar position="top" var="tabbar" modifier="top-border">
  <ons-tab active="true" class="center" page="cat1.html">cat1</ons-tab> 
  <ons-tab class="center" page="cat2.html">cat2</ons-tab>    
  <ons-tab class="center" page="cat3.html">cat3</ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>

<!-- CATEGORY 1 -->    
<ons-template type="text/ons-template" id="cat1.html">
  <ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll>
    <ons-carousel-item ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]">  
      <ons-list>  
        <ons-list-item ng-repeat="j in ['Americano','Espresso','Ristretto']">
            <ul><li>{{ j }}</li></ul>
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
  </ons-carousel-item>
    </ons-carousel>
</ons-template>  

<!-- CATEGORY 2 -->    
<ons-template type="text/ons-template" id="cat2.html">
  <ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll>
    <ons-carousel-item>  
      <ons-list>  
        <ons-list-item ng-repeat="j in ['Espresso','Ristretto','Doppio']">
            <ul><li>{{ j }}</li></ul>
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
  </ons-carousel-item>
    </ons-carousel>
</ons-template>  

<!-- CATEGORY 3 -->    
<ons-template type="text/ons-template" id="cat3.html">
  <ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll>
    <ons-carousel-item>  
      <ons-list>  
        <ons-list-item ng-repeat="j in ['Ristretto','Doppio','Espresso']">
            <ul><li>{{ j }}</li></ul>
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
  </ons-carousel-item>
    </ons-carousel>
</ons-template>
```

So every time a user clicks on a tab in the tabbar like cat1 the data for cat1 gets displayed. And this works great. But I want the user to be able to swipe through the categories. So if I am at cat1 and I swipe left cat2 has to be shown and also become active in the tabbar above. The same when I slide again to the left or when I slide to the right cat1 has to be shown and become active.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ons-postchange` attribute to specify a custom behavior when the "postchange" event is fired ([see documentation](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-carousel.html)). The behavior, in this case, would be to change the tabbar active tab, and you can do it with `setActiveTab(index, [options])` ([see documentation](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-tabbar.html)).